# declare/initialize big array as global/static/local

Tags: arrays, static, global, image-size

I figure there are 3 parameters that affect the executable size when defining big data-structures, for example arrays.
1. scope where it is defined: global/local
2. static or not
3. initialized or not

so for example, 
A. - image size: **77KB**

```
int main (void) {

    /*static*/int array[100000] = {0};
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

B. - **77KB**

```
int main (void) {

    static int array[100000] = {0};
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

C. - **467KB**

```
int main (void) {
    static int array[100000] = {1};
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

D. - **77KB**

```
int main (void) {
    /*static*/ int array[100000] = {1};
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

E. - **77KB**

```
static int array[100000] = {0};

int main (void) {
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

F. - **467KB**

```
static int array[100000] = {1};

int main (void) {
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

G. - **467KB**

```
/*static*/ int array[100000] = {1};

int main (void) {
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

H. - **77KB**

```
/*static*/ int array[100000] = {0};

int main (void) {
    printf("%d", array[100]); return 0;
}
```

It's easy to see why local array (initialize or not) is 77KB as long as it's not static. (case A. and B.)
However, static and local, even if not initialized is still 467KB (case B).
how come?

regarding the global definition:
static, and un-initialized is 77KB (case E) . how come?

I hope you can put some order and explain what happens behind the scenes...